# How to show button after clicking on a span?

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide the button and show it after 
the span its click on.

How would I be able to show this?

```
<textarea id="AtD_0" class="spellcheck_textarea " name="txtPosComment" 
rows="7" style="height: 129px;"></textarea>

<span id="AtD_1">
<span class="AtD_proofread_button"></span>
</span>

 <button type="button" id="btnNext" >Next1 </button>

/* css  */
.AtD_proofread_button 
{
   width: 126px;
   height: 30px;
   background-image: url('writing.gif');
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set css to none

```
button#btnNext{
   display:none;
  }
```

Apply onclick listener on span

```
<span class="AtD_proofread_button" onclick="showButton()"></span>
```

Finally the function:

```
function showButton(){
document.getElementById("btnNext").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show something in many ways, such as:

1. `display: none;` which acts as if the element wasn't in the page.
2. `visibility: hidden;` which makes the element fully transparent.
3. `position: absolute;` and change `top` and `left` to move it out of the screen.

You can change the style of an element in JavaScript with `element.style.propertyName = value`. For example:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").style.display = "none";
```